# WPF:MenuItem Command Canexecute not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

Ok so my requirement is quite simple

If the submenuitem is not enabled i should disable the parent Menuitem.

Here is the code.

```
<Grid>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="File" >
                <MenuItem Header="Open" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=subMenu2}">                    
                    <MenuItem Header="Open_Extended1" x:Name="subMenu2" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Add"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
```

And for the code-behind :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
public class SomeCommand : System.Windows.Input.ICommand
{
    private ViewModel Model;

    public SomeCommand(ViewModel model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return Model.IsEnabled;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {

    }
}
public class ViewModel : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private System.Boolean mIsEnabled;

    public System.Boolean IsEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return mIsEnabled;
        }
        set
        {
            mIsEnabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsEnabled");
        }
    }

    private SomeCommand mSomeCommand;

    public SomeCommand SomeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mSomeCommand == null)
            {
                mSomeCommand = new SomeCommand(this);
            }
            return mSomeCommand;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that the Open MenuItem is enabled until it is hovered that is it is not disable by default, because the CanExecute of the subMenuItem command is getting called when Open Menuitem is hovered.

Not when we click on the 'File' MenuItem

So is there is any way to focus the submenuitem so that it's CanExecute gets called?

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement goes directly against the design of the Menu classes. Getting that sub-sub-menu to refresh without showing it will be very tricky and messy.

But that's not a big problem,  you can easily solve it in your ViewModel. Introduce an `OpenEnabled` property and bind to that.

Comment: Ok basically this is a Usercontrol and it has been used in many views with different ViewModels with different return type for CanExecute for every ViewModel, so it will be lengthy to define a property in every ViewModel and bind it.

Comment: I have a solution (more like a Hack) that i write the same command in the parent MenuItem Command="{Binding SomeCommand}", the execute part will not get called when it gets clicked and CanExecute will get called once File Menu is opened, but i choose to believe there is a better alternative.

Comment: When this piece appears in many Views then it should have its own (Sub)ViewModel. In general you can have multiple Views for one VM but not the other way around.

Comment: It is sort of odd to have a (Main?) menu as a UserControl on many Forms. The traditional approach is one main Form (with 1 menu) that hosts content in a Frame or TabControl.

Comment: Yes i agree, the thing is it has it's own ViewModel but the CanExecute part is getting overloaded in the derived classes that is why it's making pretty hard for me to track it.

Comment: When CanExecute is protected virtual the base class should be able to derive an `OpenEnabled` value from that.

Answer (score 0):

You should create one more `command` for `Open Menu item` as:

```
public RelayCommand OpenCommand { get; set; }
```

Now bind the Open `MenuItem` to this `Command` :

```
<MenuItem Header="Open" Command="{Binding Command}">
```

And the `CanExecute` def would be:

```
 public bool CanExecuteOpen
    {
        get
        {
            //Can also check several menu items command here
            return CanExecuteOpen_Extended1;
        }
    }


 public bool CanExecuteOpen_Extended1
        {
            get
            {
                //Any logic for this command
                return false;
            }
        }
```

> ***Ideally it would be much more simpler if you'll be generating the `MenuItems` from `ViewModel` then a generic definition for enabling
>   `Parent` `menu Item` can be written easily. But since your menu items
>   are fixed in XAML we have to specify the which child item command
>   should be checked for a parent.***